# Extracting data from API with pagination offset using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am having a below API

```
http://example.com/?mdule=API&method=Live.getLastVisitsDetails&filter_limit=2000&filter_offset=0
```

Have to extract more data by increasing the offset into 2000

```
http://example.com/?mdule=API&method=Live.getLastVisitsDetails&filter_limit=2000&filter_offset=2000

http://example.com/?mdule=API&method=Live.getLastVisitsDetails&filter_limit=2000&filter_offset=4000

http://example.com/?mdule=API&method=Live.getLastVisitsDetails&filter_limit=2000&filter_offset=6000
```

I have a maximum of 6000 records. I don't know how to pass the offset value of every 2000 in the data factory

I can able to extract individually with the above links but wanted to do it automatically for all 6000 records.

Can anyone show me some documentation or advise how to execute this in the datafactory?

I saw the pagination documentation, but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Extracting data using copy activity from rest API**

***Step1:*** Create a ***new pipeline*** and add a Copy Data activity.

***Step2:*** Configure the ***source*** of copy activity, adding a ***pagination rule*** configured as below

[image: Ref1]

Follow this sample [**URL**](https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1) and also make sure `={offset}` at the end of URL.

[image: Ref2]

***Pagination rule*** either select ***option1*** or ***option2*** .In my case I selected `Range:0:8:2`

[image: Ref3]

In your scenario you can  follow the range as below  :

- **Option1:** `QueryParameter.{offset}: Range:0:6000:2000`
- **Option2:** `AbsoluteUrl.{offset}:Range:0:6000:2000`

Range option are using `0` as the start value,`6000` as the max value, and increasing by `2000` each time.

[image: Ref4]

[image: Ref5]

**Storage account**

[image: Ref6]

For more detail information refer this official [**article**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#example-1-variables-in-queryparameters).