# Synapse/ADF "errorCode": "2200", "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=JsonInvalidDataFormat

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am making a rest call using a copy activity to write data to a datalake storage. Source is a **rest dataset** and sink is a **json**. If I use a **http binary dataset** it works fine, but then I can not perform pagination in an easy way. I am getting the following **error**:

```json
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=JsonInvalidDataFormat,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error occurred when deserializing source JSON file ''. Check if the data is in valid JSON object format.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "ingest json to landing",
    "details": []
}
```

If I only preview the data in adf I am getting the following error:

Error code
21155
Details
Error occurred when deserializing source JSON file ''. Check if the data is in valid JSON object format.

**If I make the same call with postman, no issues, but the body comes back as text and looks as follows:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Ile.png)

```json
[
   {
      "Data":1561,
      "Number":156,
      "ID":1565,
      "TypeID":15,
      "Type":"sdfg",
      "Comments":"jbgijdresbgiesugbiiergburesgbiergb breijfberiugbi iuergiuer erguiergeriu erreuguierh guierhger eu u geir er erug iug    eruhiuguiergiuguer  er ug e  eruhgeuirge erug  erugeurhgeueruig .\nTips\n1.\trjgnrig reigeirg  eirghi : \nall erjgeriugher ergierig I er gheh erh eirghherigerg ger er ghiergier  eh egrigerig  eg . \n2.   Ewgheri ughergh erh  r   erhgerh:\ergjoi ihg iergierg iererigiergi er gieriger er gier iergpai g aei[g rhe agieg i[e I erg hhg rggergieerig ei gerh ergio ehaigneigrdrg dosg .\n3.  Jsbdiujasbfib:\npay erkgierogh erigerho ig er  erh oegiuerghe g e ir oego gerghierghe  ge rgerihgeri gegh eregh.\n"
   },
{
      "Data":1561,
      "Number":156,
      "ID":1565,
      "TypeID":15,
      "Type":"sdfg",
      "Comments":"jbgijdresbgiesugbiiergburesgbiergb breijfberiugbi iuergiuer erguiergeriu erreuguierh guierhger eu u geir er erug iug    eruhiuguiergiuguer  er ug e  eruhgeuirge erug  erugeurhgeueruig .\nTips\n1.\trjgnrig reigeirg  eirghi : \nall erjgeriugher ergierig I er gheh erh eirghherigerg ger er ghiergier  eh egrigerig  eg . \n2.   Ewgheri ughergh erh  r   erhgerh:\ergjoi ihg iergierg iererigiergi er gieriger er gier iergpai g aei[g rhe agieg i[e I erg hhg rggergieerig ei gerh ergio ehaigneigrdrg dosg .\n3.  Jsbdiujasbfib:\npay erkgierogh erigerho ig er  erh oegiuerghe g e ir oego gerghierghe  ge rgerihgeri gegh eregh.\n"
   }
]
```

**This is how the copy activity is configured:**

[image]

Does anybody know if a rest dataset supports array of jsonlines?

Comment: If you put the JSON into a validator, it shows an error: https://www.online-json.com/json-validator  It appears to return "undefined" for the Comments property. If you remove the Comments content, the JSON validates.

Comment: The json example I made a manually mistake. I fixed the example, any ideas why the pipeline is failing?

Comment: Anybody knows why with http it works, but with a rest source it is giving the deserializing error?

Comment: Did you update the sample code in the question? Because I'm still getting a parse error with a "Bad String" message in the validator.

Comment: Hi @Abashirsoldom, can you please edit and provide snippet what you have done in postman .

Comment: Is there a tool to scramble my json, it is sensitive data?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did , I took the JSON which you had pasted above . I used that JSON as source and check how ADF handled that .When i tried to preview that data in ADF ( configured the JSON as source) , it failed . I think that the character "\e" is for some reason breaking the JSON . I have no idea at this time , why thats happening

[image]

Comment: I will fix the **example**. But here is the thing, with postman no issues and the other thing os that adf is giving the exact error even if the body is **empty**.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** When you are using a binary dataset in copy activity. you only copy from binary dataset to binary dataset otherwise it will throw an error.

> **Source:**

**Request method** : **GET**

**Add additional header** : `Authorization :    Bearer < Token >`

[image]

> **Sink:**

If you want multiple responses into a single file it will break the JSON format and lead to invalid JSON. Please change the file pattern to an **Array of object** or **Set of object**.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

For more details refer this [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582885/extracting-data-from-api-with-pagination-offset-using-azure-data-factory/72600722#72600722) thread and [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory)

Comment: Thx for the explanation. I tried that, but still got the same error. The error states that the problem is in the source.